# Refreshing Offline OData : Clean up non-matching entities on client?

Tags: odata, sapui5, offline, sap-cloud-platform

Regarding on offline-enabled SAPUI5 / Cordova app deployed through SAP Cloud Platform Mobile Service..

I Recently saw a blog mentioning how non-matching offline entities can be removed after a refresh using the config.

https://blogs.sap.com/2017/08/04/offline-odata-new-features/

Ability to clean up non-matching entities on client

There was no additional detail provided so can anyone shed some light on it as the feature could be really useful.

The alternative would be to perform DELETES on all non-matching offline data

Answer (score 0):

The Solution was to set "Local Data Expiration" to 0 in the Offline Configuration of Mobile Services.